# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. Flutter build Appbundle Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When running "flutter build appbundle" on my vs code terminal appear error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\MyApps\FLUTTER\Game\game\android\app\build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  ```
            def localProperties = new Properties()
        def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
        if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
                localProperties.load(reader)
            }
        }

        def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
        if (flutterRoot == null) {
            throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define 
     location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
        }

        def flutterVersionCode = 
    localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
        if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
            flutterVersionCode = '1'
        }

        def flutterVersionName = 
    localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
        if (flutterVersionName == null) {
            flutterVersionName = '1.0'
        }

        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
        apply from: 
    "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

        def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
        def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
        if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
            keystoreProperties.load(new 
    FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))    //line 31
        }




        android {
            compileSdkVersion 30

            sourceSets {
                main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            }

            lintOptions {
                disable 'InvalidPackage'
            }

            defaultConfig {
                // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID
  ```

  (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
  applicationId "com.example.game"
  minSdkVersion 16
  targetSdkVersion 30
  versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
  versionName flutterVersionName
  }

  ```
            signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ?
  ```

  file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
  storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
  }
  }
  buildTypes {
  release {
  signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
  }

  ```
        }

        flutter {
            source '../..'
        }

        dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
   jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        }
  ```

Comment: Can you add your android build.gradle lines including line 31?

Comment: Question Updated